# Use azure push notification hub in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have an app which will be receiving push notifications.i have sample app which is designed to work with this scenario.i have completed following steps

- Config.xml file origin attribute.
- javascript code for registering device.
- necessary files js for files included with plugin imported to index.html.
- google api key has provided to azure.(as im testing this on android)

I can send test messages using inbuilt debugger in azure notification hub.when i send message it shows message sent successfully.but I'm not receiving any messages.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/17/push-notifications-to-phonegap-apps-using-notification-hubs-integration.aspx

this is link for sample app.

Comment: Could you go through [diagnostics guideline](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/) and if it doesn't help, update with what you've learned?

Comment: thanx nikita i already made it.

Comment: Could you post in the answers what was your solution? So that if it happens to someone else they could try the same thing?

Comment: its here mzonerz.wordpress.com(im not promoting)

Answer (score 1):

Overall, if you don't receive a push with Azure Notification Hubs, you can almost always troubleshoot it using [diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/).

Regarding the original question, @mzonerz had been able to resolve his issue and posted a detailed blog post about it at [windows azure Push Notification sample app with Phonegap](https://mzonerz.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/windows-azure-push-notification-sample-app-with-phonegap/).